# Javascript appendChild callback?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add an HTML5 video to a page with the following code:

```
document.querySelector("#mydiv").appendChild(video);
console.debug(document.querySelector("video").clientWidth);
```

My problem is, the second line returns 0 because it takes a while for the `video` tag to load the video it's going to play. If I manually type the second line in the console once the page is loaded, I get the actual value. Is there a better way to get this value than using timeouts to periodically check if the value's been updated?

Comment: `appendChild` callback? Are you looking for an event instead? Eg  [`loadedmetadata`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#event-media-loadedmetadata) for example?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks! I didn't know this. If you post an answer saying this I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is one-threaded.
You should to drop your code to event-loop, this allows the js with DOM work.

Just try followed:

```
document.querySelector("#mydiv").appendChild(video);
setTimeout(function(){
  console.debug(document.querySelector("video").clientWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar and stumbled upon this question, as I though maybe there is a callback for this. Turns out there is not. So here is another way of doing it using [Window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

It would look something like this:

```js
// Prepare the new element
let video = document.createElement('video');

// Add the element to the DOM. Works with any element
document.querySelector("#mydiv").appendChild(video);

// Updateing the DOM will cause a re-render, which we can hook into
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  console.debug(document.querySelector("video").clientWidth);
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">Video goes here:</div>
```

Check the console to see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `video.onloadstart` event to the element.

```
video.onloadstart(getClientWidth);
document.querySelector("#mydiv").appendChild(video);
function getClientWidth() {
    console.debug(document.querySelector("video").clientWidth);
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadstart.asp).